# Running parallel tests using mstest with PowerShell workflow

Tags: powershell, mstest, powershell-workflow

A newbie and first question on this forum. My first script successfully runs tests in parallel using mstest with PowerShell v4.0 workflow. But as "InlineScript" has the limitation of running 5 in parallel, trying to re-design the script to something without "InlineScript". While I could make the second script work for single test with hard coded test name, getting issues when I try to pull all the tests for run. Please take a look at both the scripts and suggest:

First Script:

```
workflow Primary_Tests
{
    $Workspace = "E:\Vishal_PS_Workspace"
    $mstest = "C:\VisualStudio12\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"
    $testlocation = "$Workspace\TEST\TestBin"

    $RunName = Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-dd-T-HH\hmm"
    mkdir "$Workspace\TestResults\Results-$RunName"
    $resultsDir = "$Workspace\TestResults\Results-$RunName"
    $results = "/resultsfile:$resultsDir\$RunName.trx"

    InlineScript { cd $Using:testlocation }

    $tests = @("Test_01", "Test_006", "Test 013", "ST-002-002", "ST-001-002", "ST-032-002", "ST-012-002", "Test 016", "Test 143")

    ForEach -Parallel -ThrottleLimit 10 ($test in $tests)
    {

        InlineScript { & $Using:mstest /TestContainer:"$Using:testlocation\$Using:test.webtest" /resultsfile:"$Using:resultsDir\$Using:test.trx" }
    }
}

Primary_Tests
```

Second Script:

```
Workflow Parallel_Tests
{
    $Workspace = "E:\Vishal_PS_Workspace"
    $mstest = "C:\VisualStudio12\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"
    $testlocation = "$Workspace\TEST\TestBin"

    $RunName = Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-dd-T-HH\hmm"
    mkdir "$Workspace\TestResults\Results-$RunName"
    $resultsDir = "$Workspace\TestResults\Results-$RunName"
    $results = "/resultsfile:$resultsDir\$RunName.trx"

    $arguments = " /testcontainer:" + "$testlocation\" + "Test_01.webtest"
    $tests = @("Test_01")

    ForEach -Parallel -ThrottleLimit 10 ($test in $tests)
    {

        Invoke-Expression "$mstest $arguments $results"

    }
}
Parallel_Tests
```

Answer (score 0):

Some more retry and I could make it work by using nested
foreach. Thank you anyways.